# How to Show percentage in WPF datagridProgressbarcolumn along with progress?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, datatemplate, datarow

I am used the below codes in datagridtemplateprogressbarcolumn and its working fine progress
But how to give the percentage along with this below code.
The below code is working for progress only,How to show percentage along with that code.

In xaml file:-

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="*" Visibility="Visible">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Progress, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" />                                       
 </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

In c#code:-

```
DataRow row2 = new DataRow();
row2["Progress"] = current;
```

This progress is working fine,But how to show percentage along with this datagridprogressbarcolumn in WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it (not tested, but you should get the idea):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress" Width="*" Visibility="Visible">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Progress}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=Progress, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Height="25" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

BTW, normally the binding for your ProgressBar should be `OneWay`.

Comment: i liked ur code,its working when give separeate datatemplatecolumn,not along inside the progressbar column.so how to inside datagridtemplatecolumnprogressbar?

Comment: @NvadeepKumar: It works inside the progressbar column as well. Just confirmed.

Comment: @NvadeepKumar: I tested and expanded my code. It should simply be a matter of copy-paste for you now.

Comment: :Ya its working,but color is am given dark green,but its shows very very light green,how to show as dark green?

Comment: @NvadeepKumar: You should ask that in a separate question to make it beneficial for other people too.

Comment: Ok,am asked separetely